# What is the variance of a variable given itself?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation, variance

Given an event $X$, what is $\operatorname{var}[X\mid X]$. In addition, what would $E[\operatorname{var}(X\mid X)]$ be? I have been told that $\operatorname{var}[X\mid X] = 0$, but I don't understand why - $\operatorname{var}[X\mid X]$ should be a random variable, and $X\mid X$ has no more information than $X$, so $\operatorname{var}[X\mid X]$ should equal $\operatorname{var}[X]$, correct?

Comment: The most frequent MathJax typesetting error on m.s.e. occurs repeatedly in this question and in both of the posted answers, and I fixed it in all of them.  I surmise that there must be some people to whom this sort of thing is not conspicuous. $\qquad$

Comment: Some errors in the question: (1) It says "event" where it should say "random variable"; (2) It refers to something called $X\mid X$.  There's no such thing.  The notation $\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y)$ is NOT the expected value of an object called $X\mid Y$.  Rather, it is the conditional expected value given $Y$, of the random variable $X$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition,
$$ \mathrm{var}[X\mid X=x]=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X\mid X=x])^2\mid X=x]$$

But $\mathbb{E}[X\mid X=x]=x$, so
$$ \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X\mid X=x])^2\mid X=x]=\mathbb{E}[(X-x)^2\mid X=x]=0$$

Therefore $\mathrm{var}[X\mid X]=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$X\mid X$ (or more specifically $X\mid X=x$) *does* have more information than just $X$. If someone tells you that $X$ has a particular, specific value, then how many possible values can $X$ have at that moment? Only one, so the conditional variance must be zero. You can easily verify this algebraically, as carmichael561 does in his answer.

The situation is similar to that of conditional probabilities. The probability that $A$ occurs given that $A$ occurs is unity.